# Filtering with multiple conditions and creating new csv

Tags: python, pandas

[Look at the variations of code I tried here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWRrh.png)

I'm trying to use Pandas to filter rows with multiple conditions and create a new csv file with only those rows. I've tried several different ways and then commented out each of those attempts (sometimes I only tried one condition for simplicity but it still didn't work). When the csv file is created, the filters weren't applied.

[This is my updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhK1h.png)
I got it to work for condition #1, but I'm not sure how to add/apply condition #2. I tried a lot of different combinations. I know the code I put in the linked image wouldn't work for applying the 2nd condition because all I did was assign the variable, but it seemed too cumbersome to try to show all the ways I tried to do it. Any hints on that part?

```
    df = pd.read_csv(excel_file_path)

#condition #1
is_report_period = (df["Report Period"]=="2015-2016") | \
    (df["Report Period"]=="2016-2017") | \
        (df["Report Period"]=="2017-2018") | \
            (df["Report Period"]=="2018-2019")

#condition #2
is_zip_code = (df["Zip Code"]<"14800")

new_df = df[is_report_period]
```

Comment: You are not assigning the filters to a new dataframe and you are just recreating your original dataframe. I saw a `new_df` variable in the commented out code, uncomment the code and use `new_df.to_csv(filename)` or add `df = ` in front of the code that is doing filtering

Comment: Thanks @MichaelVine. I edited my original post with an update.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add code snippets instead of code images :)

Comment: @whereelse you can use pastebin to paste your code and add the link in the question instead of the images

Comment: Adding Sample input and desired output also helps to pinpoint the error! – @whereelse

Answer (score 1):

you can easily achieve this by using the '&':

```
new_df = df[is_report_period & is_zip_code]
```

also, you can make your code more readable and easy for you to apply changes
in the filtering by using this method:

```
Periods = ["2015-2016","2016-2017","2017-2018","2018-2019"]
is_report_period = df["Report Period"].isin(Periods)
```

this way you can easily alter your filter when needed, and it's
easier for you to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Ohad. When I try using the '&' I get the following error: 
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str

Comment: Hi, this is because your #2 condition refers to zip codes as string, but they are probably an integer in the dataframe.
your code:
    is_zip_code = (df["Zip Code"]<"14800")
should be:
    is_zip_code = (df["Zip Code"]<14800)